# check if select all checkbox has been clicked

Tags: javascript, telerik, client-side, radgrid

so i have a telerik client grid with a gridclientselectcolumn. Im trying to figure out when the select all checkbox is clicked.

something like:

```
function(sender, e){
if (e.SELECTALLCHECKBOX){
//do something
}
```

is there a way to simply check if the checkbox has been clicked.

Thanks

Comment: please share your html code

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the guy who always recommends jQuery but . . . I would recommend jQuery.

```
$('#selectAllCheckbox:checked').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') {
        $('#otherCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $('#otherCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
}
```

Be careful about using .prop() as opposed to .val(). There are some [subtle differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) that can get you in trouble.

Comment: thnks for the answer but i have to use javascript. i know how the select all checkbox works. im just trying to intercept the event of clicking the select all checkbox before it goes off and selects everything